# How can I use a Seekbar as a brightness slider?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using the `GLSurfaceView` Renderer. I want changes to a seek bar's progress to increase the brightness of a `GLSurfaceView` proportionally.

How do I apply a color matrix to a GLSurface view? Is there a better way?